# How to make my plot smoother with my data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have such data:

```
[38, 54, 38, 52, 36, 49, 34, 45, 31, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 56]
```

which I draw by this way:

```
plt.plot(x_arr, linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

and receive such plot:

[image]

is it possible to make this plot smoother ? I tried to use

```
np.linspace
```

and [such example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-plot-a-smooth-curve-in-matplotlib/) also. But I received such error:

```
ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.
```

maybe I did smth wrong or I have to use another way for smoothing? This data I can't change because they were received from my experiments :(

Comment: What do you mean by "smoother"? Make lines less edgy or data less spread?

Comment: @go2nirvana lines less edgy, because data can't be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For controlling the amount of smoothing, you can use a [Gausian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

y = np.array([38, 54, 38, 52, 36, 49, 34, 45, 31, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 56])
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])


plt.plot(x, y, label='original')

interp_x = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 200)
interp_y = np.interp(interp_x, x, y)
for smoothing in (0.5, 1, 2, 10): # choose a smoothing value that works for your data
    smoothed_y = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(interp_y, smoothing)
    
    plt.plot(interp_x, smoothed_y, label='smoothing='+str(smoothing))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot showing smoothed data]

Comment: if I use your code with my data I receive only two lines

Comment: can you try it with my data pls? because it doesn't represent it correctly as I see

Comment: yes, thank you so much, it is good enough :)

Answer (score 2):

I am suspect that you get that error because you are using the build-in list instead of a NumPy array. To achieve what you want to do with your data, it should be like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

y=np.array([38, 54, 38, 52, 36, 49, 34, 45, 31, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 56])
x=np.array(list(range(len(y_arr))))

X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x, y)

X_ = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)

plt.plot(X_, Y_)
plt.show()
```

[image: example output]

Notice the following:

- the data you provided are the y-values
- using the np.array instead of the Python building list in x and y

Comment: where do you store `x=np.array(list(range(len(y_arr))))` `y_arr` here?

Comment: the y np.array are the experiment readings (they are the y values) and x np.array is just a list from 0 to the number of readings that we have here. e.g. [0,1,2,...]

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is less "edgy" lines, then you could apply a quadratic spline interpolation like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

# Define data and x-axis
data = [38, 54, 38, 52, 36, 49, 34, 45, 31, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 
        46, 32, 42, 30, 52, 36, 51, 36, 49, 34, 46, 32, 42, 30, 56]
x_axis = np.arange(0, len(data))

# Spline interpolation
f = interpolate.interp1d(x_axis, data, kind = 'quadratic')
x_spline = np.linspace(0, len(data) - 1, 1000)

# Plot stuff
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_axis, data, 'k.', label = 'Data')
plt.plot(x_spline, f(x_spline), 'k--', label = 'Spline interpolation')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot:
[spline interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1JEq.png)

You should however be careful using this as it does not necessarily represent your data in a good way.